# jpos.JposException: It could not complete output within the specified period

Tags: java, printing, point-of-sale

I am working on a POS system which is designed in JAVA. For printing we are using USB Epson-TMH6000III Printer to print the receipts. I am getting 'jpos.JposException: It could not complete output within the specified period.'

I tried increasing baud rate-currently 19200(as I read this sol on a web site this), but it did not work. Please suggest any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest you to improve your question by reading the [Minimal, Complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

I had this error before. In my case, it is due to very long string inputted to printer. I solved this by breaking down the string into smaller parts then print each part.